# Cómo permitir el acceso a métodos de una clase sólo a instancias de una clase de un tipo determinado

Tags: java, interface

Estoy tratando de limitar el acceso a un método de una clase creada por mi a exclusivamente instancias de un tipo de clase determinada que contiene como campo a mis clase CustomList
Deseo que sólo puedan añadir elementos a ese CustomList las instancias de un tipo de clase concreto que también tiene como campo ese CustomList.

Había pensado que quizá con una interface se podía hacer pero no he sido capaz de implementarlo.

El esquema sería algo así:

```
 public class CustomList {
        private List<Evento> lista;

        private void añadirEvento(Evento evento){
        //deseo que sólo puedan acceder a este método las instancia de la clase 
        //Prueba
         lista.add(evento);
    }


public class Prueba{

        private CustomList listaEventos;

        public Prueba(CustomList lista){
        this.listaEventos = lista;
}
  //Deseo que sólo esta clase Prueba pueda llamar al método añadirEvento de CustomList
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que comentas lo de la interfaz, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
public class AppendableCustomList implements CustomList {

    protected List<Evento> lista;

    //no forma parte de la interfaz
    private void añadirEvento(Evento evento) {
     lista.add(evento);
    }

    //Otros métodos que estarán incluidos en la interfaz

}
```

La clase Prueba tendrá una instancia de esta clase:

```
public class Prueba {

    AppendableCustomList MyCustomList = ....
}
```

El resto de clases trabajará con la misma instancia... pero la recibirán como interfaz que no tiene ese método:

```
public OtraClase {

    CustomList cl = getCustomList();
}
```

Comment: Creo que si que podría servirme lo que propones pasando la misma instancia a una clase como clase pura y a las de otros tipos como interfaz. Muchas gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a cambiar a *protected* el modificador del método ***añadirEvento***
y añadir extends en la clase Prueba.

```
 public class CustomList {
        private List<Evento> lista;

        protected void añadirEvento(Evento evento){
        //deseo que sólo puedan acceder a este método las instancia de la clase 
        //Prueba
         lista.add(evento);
    }


public class Prueba extends CustomList{

        private CustomList listaEventos;

        public Prueba(CustomList lista){
        this.listaEventos = lista;
}
  //Deseo que sólo esta clase Prueba pueda llamar al método añadirEvento de CustomList
}
```

Comment: Podría ser una solución válida pero tendría que crear una clase puente ya que Prueba debe extender de otra clase pero creo que es una solución viable. Muchas gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0):

Por cuestiones estructurales de Java, los modificadores de acceso no permiten discernir entre un "tipo" de clase u otra, sino que provee restricciones con respecto a la misma clase o el paquete al cual pertenece.

Se me ocurren dos maneras de implementar lo que buscas.

1. El método solo puede ser instanciado si la clase otorga un parámetro "Valido". En caso de que se haga desde otra clase, la CustomList creada será nula. Luego será cuestión de hacer una comprobación, con un getter para obtener la lista y verificar si la misma es nula.

   ```
   public class CustomList 
           {
           public CustomList(String tipo)
           {
           private List<Evento> lista
           if (tipo.equals("Valido"))
                   lista = new List<evento>;
           else
                   lista = null;
           private void añadirEvento(Evento evento){
           lista.add(evento);
           }

   public class Prueba
           {
           private CustomList listaEventos = new CustomList("Valido");
           public Prueba(CustomList lista){
           this.listaEventos = lista;
           }
   }
   ```
2. Si sabes que es absolutamente restringido a una sola clase y nunca será accesible desde otra, lo puedes hacer de esta manera.

   ```
   public class CustomList 
           {
           public CustomList(String clase)
           {
           private List<Evento> lista
           if (clase.equals("Prueba"))
                   lista = new List<evento>;
           else
                   lista = null;
           private void añadirEvento(Evento evento){
           lista.add(evento);
           }

   public class Prueba
           {
           private CustomList listaEventos = new CustomList(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
           public Prueba(CustomList lista){
           this.listaEventos = lista;
           }
   }
   ```

Comment: No estoy seguro de que en mi caso esta sea una solución válida ya que la CustomList será referenciada en varios tipos de clase al mismo tiempo y lo que deseo es que un sólo tipo de clase sea el que puede añadir o eliminar elementos a la List. Se me pasaba por la cabeza si quizá sea posible hacerlo mediante una interface que haga saltar un evento que sea manejado por la clase CustomList para añadir o eliminar un elemento, pero no se si esto es una forma correcta de solventar este problema